# Limit JTextField character input

Tags: character, limit, document, jtextfield

So I searched all over internet and in every single topic I found this solution for limitting JTextField input.

```
public class FixedDocument extends PlainDocument {
  private int limit;
  // optional uppercase conversion
  private boolean toUppercase = false;

  FixedDocument(int limit) {
   super();
   this.limit = limit;
   }

  FixedDocument(int limit, boolean upper) {
   super();
   this.limit = limit;
   toUppercase = upper;
   }

  public void insertString (int offset, String  str, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
   if (str == null){
       return;
   }
    if ((getLength() + str.length()) <= limit) {
     if (toUppercase) str = str.toUpperCase();
     super.insertString(offset, str, attr);
     }
   }
}
```

but I have a problem with that code. This code line "super.insertString(offset, str, attr);" gives me error:

```
no suitable method found for insertString(int,java.lanf.String,javax.print.attribute.AttributeSet)
 method javax.swing.text.PlainDocument.insertString(int,java.lang.String,javax.text.AttributeSet) is not applicable
  (actual argument javax.printattribute.AttributeSet cannot be converted to javax.swing.text.AttributeSet by method invocation conversion)
```

anyone got any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I would use a DocumentFilter for this myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your importing the wrong AttributeSet class. You are importing `javax.print.attribute.AttributeSet`, when you should be importing `javax.swing.text.AttributeSet`, and the error message pretty much tells you this.  Again, myself, I'd use a DocumentFilter for this as that is what it was built for.